# MongoDb - mapReduce(...) not working

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

**Sample doc:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51cd7274267d959cb9f95cea"),
    "creation_time" : 100,
    "delivered" : true,
    "id" : 1,
    "user_id" : 10
}
```

**Map function:**

```
db.system.js.save({
    _id: "mapDummy",
    value: function(){
        emit(this.user_id,this.user_id);
    }
});
```

**Reduce function:**

```
db.system.js.save({
    _id: "reduceDummy",
    value: function(key,values){
        return Array.sum(values);
    }
});
```

**mapReduce(...) function call:**

```
db.newsdb.mapReduce("mapDummy", "reduceDummy", {out: "notifications_result", query: {delivered:true}});

{
    "result" : "notifications_result",
    "timeMillis" : 16,
    "counts" : {
        "input" : 12,
        "emit" : 0,
        "reduce" : 0,
        "output" : 0
    },
    "ok" : 1,
}
```

Why `emit:0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because you use a string and not a function to the call:

```
db.newsdb.mapReduce("mapDummy", "reduceDummy", {out: "notifications_result", query: {delivered:true}});
```

Instead of Map/Reduce I would suggest you use the aggregation framework (A/F) anyway. You seem to be doing a simple group by on user_id, which is much better served with A/F as it's a lot faster and easier to use:

```
db.newsdb.aggregate( { $group: { _id: user_id, count: { $sum: 1 } } } );
```

Comment: +1 Yes, that was the problem. This mapReduce sample was just to try my hands on it. Actually I want to perform some complex aggregation task which is not possible through A/F

Answer (score 0):

After an hour of failed attempts...!

```
let maps = function() {
          emit(this. user_id, 1)
        };
let reduces = function(keys, vals){
          return Array.sum(vals);
        };

result.collection.mapReduce(maps, reduces, { out: { reduce: 'test_collection' 
}, jsMode: true, verbose: true})
.then(res=> console.log(res.stats))
.catch(err=> console.log({err}));
```

..I established that 'mapReduce' does not accept 'Fat Arrows' =>=>=>=>|_ Maps || Reduces!!